# Jquery Variable Not Working With Click Event

Tags: jquery, variables, object

Why the heck doesn't this work??!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var chooseSection = $("#chooseSection");
    var diabetesSection = $(".diabetesSection");

    chooseSection.live('click', function() {
        diabetesSection.css('display','block');
        setTimeout(function() {
            diabetesSection.addClass('fullfadeIn');
        },20);
        console.log("clicked")
    });

    });
```

The HTML

```
<div class="row orders-header">
    <div id="orders-back" class="columns">
        <div id="orderCol" class="columns">
            <div class="theBackBtn">Active Orders</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="chooseSection" class="columns">
        <div class="order-header-btn">
            Choose Section...
        </div>
        <div id="popUp" class="diabetesSection" style="display: none; ">
                        <div class="pop-arrow"></div>
                        <div class="diabetesSection-options">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Suggested</li>
                                <li>Labs</li>
                                <li>Medications</li>
                                <li>Other Tests</li>
                                <li>Referrals</li>
                                <li>Office Procedures</li>
                                <li>Sets</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns" style="width:50%; float:right;">
        <input class="general-searchbar orders-search" placeholder="Search Orders...">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Does the element with class `diabetesSection` exist at the creation of the document? If not, that's the reason, and you should move the declaration to inside the event handler.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Also, you shouldn't bind a live event inside a `$(document).ready()`. It's not necessary since the element doesn't need to be on the page to bind the event.

Comment: I think you might be right Rob. The element doesn't exist when the script is loaded. Let me try something and get back to you on this...

Comment: Unless you are dynamically manipulating the DOM (adding and removing Sections), try using "bind" instead of "live" to handle the click event.

Comment: Hi Ron, I am dynamically manipulating the DOM alot and this is for an iPad so it's not your typical website (using live('touchstart click') alot of the time). Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I tried and it works well...

Make sure you have both the elements(element with id "chooseSection" and other with class 'diabetesSection')

Or is this specific to any browser?

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work about it?

http://jsfiddle.net/rawsmell/RU2H8/2/

It displays and adds the `class` so the div ends up with `diabetesSection fullfadeIn`. How is it supposed to work?